# using foreach for C# for Email in Asp.NetCore Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two different `IEnumerable<>`s: one to get IDs from a Gmail inbox and the other `IEnumerable<>` to get a list of `MailMessage`s, like in the code below.

```
          client.DefaultMailbox = "INBOX";
          IEnumerable<uint> sids = client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
          IEnumerable<MailMessage> AllMessage = client.GetMessages(sids);
          List<LiteInbox> allmail = new List<LiteInbox>();
```

I want to use two `foreach` loops to get the specific ID for each `MailMessage` coming from the Gmail inbox. If I iterate `foreach` inside `foreach`, that will fetch the ID for each `MailMessage`.

```
 foreach (uint ids in sids)
  {
      id = ids;
      LiteInbox lite=new LiteInbox();

      foreach(var mail in AllMessage )
      {
         lite.id=id;
         lite.sender=mail.sender;
         lite.subject=mail.subject;
      }

   }
```

For each email in the inbox, loop through the two foreach statements one at a time. If there are four unread emails, loop through each of them separately and assign an ID to each one.

```
     {   [
   {
    id: 1,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com     },
{
    id: 1,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
{
    id: 1,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
{
    id: 1,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
],
   [
   {
    id: 2,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
{
    id: 2,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
{
    id: 2,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com      },
{
    id: 2,
    subject: welcome,
    body:hbjdbjddjh,
    sender: wealsegun@gmail.com     },
]}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve and what is your problem? For now, you just show us two nested loops which infact do nothing. They don't print anything or add anything to your `allmail` List. Furthermore, you are always updating the same `lite` object as you are never creating a new one.

Comment: i want to give each of my ``MailMessage `` its appropriate ``Id`` assigned to it by gmail so that on click each email i should be able to get that mail using Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the order of `AllMessage` and `sids` is the same, and the number of elements in these lists is equal (otherwise I wouldn't know how to assign the correct id to a message) you can do the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllMessage.Count; i++) {
    LiteInbox lite=new LiteInbox();
    lite.id = sids[i];
    lite.sender=AllMessage[i].sender;
    lite.subject=AllMessage[i].subject;
    allmail.Add(lite);    
}
```

alternatively with `foreach`

```
int i = 0;  //you'll need that index to access the corresponding element in the other list
foreach (int id in sids) {
    LiteInbox lite=new LiteInbox();
    lite.id = id;
    lite.sender=AllMessage[i].sender;
    lite.subject=AllMessage[i].subject;
    allmail.Add(lite);            
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve every sid associated to every Email
if the class MailMessage has a sid property (I doubt, is MailMessage class the .Net framework one?) you need to modify the signature of one or both your `Search` and `GetMessages` so it returns something like a

```
List<Pair<uint, MailMessage>>
```

where every element of the list is the message and its ID

After that, you will not need the double foreach

Comment: But am using IEnumerable is that also possible with it

Comment: `IEnumerable <Pair<uint, MailMessage>> `? sure you can!